# ADOTable cancel updates in row before post

Tags: c++, ado, c++builder, c++builder-6

I have a remote database mysql, connected to the application (C++ Builder 6) using ADOConnection, and DBGrid, which is displayed data (ADOConnection-ADOTable-Dataset-DBGrid). 
ADOTable by default can not be edited; by clicking on the button "Edit", I write "readonly = false", and edit data.

After editing the line (for example, the cursor moved to the line above), I need to prompt the user ("Save changes? Y / N"), and when you select "No", to undo the changes. 
On request there is no problem. The question is how I should undo the changes (preferably still on the client, ie ADOTable or DBGrid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it myself. Three weeks of headache, and five rows of code.

```
if (DataSet->State == dsEdit || DataSet->State == dsInsert){
            int res = MessageBox(Handle, "Save changes?", "Confirm", MB_YESNO);
            if (res == IDNO){
                    DataSet->Cancel();
                    Abort();
            }
    }
```

Also, if we click on other field, and select "No", cursor would not move. But that's not a problem for now.